# How to get a reference to the module of a class

Tags: python

You can get the name of the module a class belongs to as follows:

```
myClass.__module__
```

How do I get a reference to the module instead? More specifically, I want to access the doc-string of the module an arbitrary class is part of. Something similar to:

```
mod = myClass.getModule() # How do I do this?
print mod.__doc__
```

Comment: You're right, but that was just an example... I'll change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look the module up in `sys.modules`:

```
import sys

mod = sys.modules[cls.__module__]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.modules[datetime.__module__].__doc__
Fast implementation of the datetime type.
```